# Plotting the equation $x - {(\cos(x) + i\sin(x))^{ix}} = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

I would like to plot this function:

$$x - {(\cos(x) + i\sin(x))^{ix}} = 0$$

I remember about $\cos(x) + i\sin(x) = e^{ix}$, so this can be written as $$x - {(e^{ix})^{ix}} = 0$$

or maybe better
$$x - {e^{ixix}} = 0$$
I know it's not *that* hard, but my math background is very rusty. I tried with wolfram, but I'm not sure why it's not plotting it. Maybe for the $i$?

Is there another tool I can use?

Comment: Well, what is $i^2$?

Comment: Try separating $x$ into real and imaginary parts as $x=a+bi$ and treating the real and imaginary parts as coordinate axes.

Comment: $(e^{ix})^{ix}=e^{-x^2}$.  Can you plot $f(x)=x-e^{-x^2}$?  Then find the value of $x$ for which $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Also, Mathematica plots this fine, use capital I for i, but {hint}, you don't need that.

Comment: @Taylor, I changed your edit because $e^{(ix)^2}$ masked an issue the OP has.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Ah, I see. Thank you for informing me.

Comment: $x - {(\cos(x) + i\sin(x))^{ix}} = 0$  is not a function, it's an equation.

Comment: The expression $(e^{ix})^{ix}$ is not “single valued”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(x)=x-(\cos x+i\sin x)^{ix}=x-e^{-x^2}$.  Plot this function and find that $f(x)=0$ when $x\approx. 0.65291862487151$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x - {(\cos(x) + i\sin(x))^{ix}} = 0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x - {(e^{ix})^{ix}} = 0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x - e^{ixix} = 0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x - e^{(ix)^2} = 0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x - e^{i^2x^2} = 0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x - e^{-x^2} = 0\Longleftrightarrow$$

(because $x$ is real we can write)

$$e^{x^2}x= 1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{x^2}= \frac{1}{x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2=\frac{\log_{10}(\frac{1}{x})}{\log_{10}(e)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2=\frac{\log_{10}(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{\ln(10)}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2=\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2=-\ln(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=e^{-\frac{W(2)}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{W(2)}{2}}$$

---

$W(x)$ is the Lambert $W$-function